# How to use sass in rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

i have installed sass by using

in my Gemfile

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

i am sure that sass was installed

but how to import it into html.erb???

Comment: Sass extends CSS. Why and how do you want to use Sass in HTML?

Answer (score 1):

SASS is a CSS-Engine

HAML is a HTML-Engine

---

using `sass-rails` is setting up your assets pipeline to also use **.sass** or **.scss** files instead of regular css files.

exmaple for **sass** is

```
a
 color: #fff
 margin: 10px
 &:hover
   color: red
```

inside of your `application.css` then you just require all those files you need to have i.e `//=require my_styles.sass`

**haml** is the template engine which allows you to use haml files. `gem 'haml-rails` is enabling it.

then you can use templates like

```
.wrapper
  %h1 My HAML Headline
  %h2= @page_title

  .col-md-12.strong
    %span GTFO :-)
```

Comment: from sass/haml to compass. ok